# How to change the filtered date format in material table react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

In material table react, I have the following columns:

```
columns={[
            {
              title: 'Name',
              field: 'name',
              type: 'string',
            },
            {
              title: 'Age',
              field: 'age',
              type: 'string',
            },
            {
              title: 'DOB',
              field: 'birthDate',
              type: 'date',
              dateSetting: {
                format: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
              },
            }
         ]}
```

When I try to filter the date column it shows filtered date as, for example, **February 24th**, but instead I want the date to be like **dd/MM/yyyy** format.

How can I change the value. I already tried giving dateSetting, but it does not work on filter.
Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve that by defining your own `filterComponent`. Here is a working example I made based on this [solution](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/671):

[image]

First, you need to create the component to be used as a filter, in my case I used `KeyboardDatePicker` from *material-ui/pickers*, but could it be anything you need:

```js
const CustomDatePicker = (props) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        margin="normal"
        id="date-picker-dialog"
        label="Date picker"
        format="dd/MM/yyyy"
        clearable
        value={date}
        onChange={(event) => {
          console.log("Date picker value: ", event);
          console.log(props.columnDef.tableData.id);

          setDate(event);
          props.onFilterChanged(props.columnDef.tableData.id, event);
        }}
        KeyboardButtonProps={{
          "aria-label": "change date"
        }}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};
```

The key aspect is to call the `onFilterChanged` function that is passed via `props`.

Then, on your column definition just implement your component, like this:

```js
 const tableColumns = [
    { title: "Client", field: "id" },
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },

    {
      title: "Date",
      field: "date",
      type: "date",
      dateSetting: { locale: "en-GB" },
      filterComponent: (props) => <CustomDatePicker {...props} />
    }
  ];
```

Full code and sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-custom-filtercomponent-v40l5?file=/src/App.js:543-828). Hope that works for you!

Comment: Just a quick note, 'event' in onChange isn't the event, it's the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import "date-fns";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const CustomDatePicker = (props) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        margin="normal"
        id="date-picker-dialog"
        label="Date picker"
        format="dd/MM/yyyy"
        clearable
        value={date}
        onChange={(event) => {
          console.log("Date picker value: ", event);
          console.log(props.columnDef.tableData.id);

          setDate(event);
          props.onFilterChanged(props.columnDef.tableData.id, event);
        }}
        KeyboardButtonProps={{
          "aria-label": "change date"
        }}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};
export default CustomDatePicker;
```

and

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import CustomDatePicker from "./customDatePicker";

const originalData = [
  {
    id: "client 1",
    name: "Anna",
    date: new Date("2021-03-01T20:11:54")
  },
  {
    id: "client 2",
    name: "Tom",
    date: new Date("2020-03-30T11:01:54")
  },
  {
    id: "client 3",
    name: "Deb",
    date: new Date("2021-02-28T21:11:54")
  }
];

export default function CustomEditComponent(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(originalData);

  const tableColumns = [
    { title: "Client", field: "id" },
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },

    {
      title: "Date",
      field: "date",
      type: "date",
      dateSetting: { locale: "en-GB" },
      filterComponent: (props) => <CustomDatePicker {...props} />
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MaterialTable
        columns={tableColumns}
        data={data}
        title="Material Table - Custom Filter Component"
        options={{ search: false, filtering: true }}
        editable={{
          onRowAdd: (newData) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                setData([...data, newData]);

                resolve();
              }, 1000);
            }),
          onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("old:", oldData);
                console.log("new:", newData);
                const dataUpdate = [...data];
                const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                dataUpdate[index] = newData;
                setData([...dataUpdate]);

                resolve();
              }, 1000);
            }),
          onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                const dataDelete = [...data];
                const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                dataDelete.splice(index, 1);
                setData([...dataDelete]);

                resolve();
              }, 1000);
            })
        }}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```