# Material Table : Custom Column Filter, unable to filter based on value selection

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I want a single select option column component, hence used `filterComponent` property of the columns-props to render a custom Single Select Material-UI component. On Change of the option the value of the Select is updated. But I also need the row data to be filtered out. How can this be achieved?

Used `customFilterAndSearch` prop supported by columns props, this is not getting invoked because of using `filterComponent` to override the existing component.

Tried calling `customFilterAndSearch` onChange of the select options, for this to work, `customFilterAndSearch` expects 2 arguments 1. option/filter value, 2. row-data. I can obtain the 1st parameter value, but is there a way to obtain row-data ?

```
{
      title: "Birth Place",
      field: "birthCity",
      lookup: birthCity,
      customFilterAndSearch: (data, rowData) => {
        console.log({ data, rowData });
        return true;
      },
      filterComponent: (props) => {
        return (
          <Select
            value={city}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setCity(e.target.value);
              props.columnDef.customFilterAndSearch(e.target.value, {}); // don't know how to idenitfy row data and send as a parameter
            }}
          >
            {Object.keys(birthCity).map((key) => {
              return <MenuItem value={key}> {key} </MenuItem>;
            })}
          </Select>
        );
      }
    }
```

Link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-galois-25eub?file=/src/Table.js)

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66460282/10569220) with an example of a custom `filterComponent`, you could follow the same approach to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks this helped solving the problem